# WIX: The following application should be closed before continuing the install

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uninstallation, close-application

my application have tray icon. when i uninstall it
i have window with the proposal to close the "my_tray_app.exe" - with text: ("*The following application should be closed before continuing the install*")

i'm use wix "CloseApplication Element (Util Extension)" to close "my_tray_app.exe" [win close app](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/closeapplication.html)

**HOW TO AVOID THIS WINDOW??**

i try play with CloseApplication attributes - but don't have result... oO

Comment: There are too many variables involved to come up with an answer. What messages does the tray app respond to, such as the end session or close messages? Does that app have any debug/trace data that can show if it even received the message? Are you sending end session or close messages in the WiX? If the app doesn't cooperate it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm use wxWidgets and use following method to close my "TrayApp.exe":

```
<util:CloseApplication Id="CloseApp" CloseMessage="yes" Target="TrayApp.exe" RebootPrompt="no" />

<Custom Action="WixCloseApplications" Before="RemoveFiles" />
```

but "TrayApp.exe" stay on taskmanager and stay on system tray!

if i try close other tray app (for example "Skype.exe") all work fine and my uninstaller closes "Skype.exe" and remove from system tray.

**may be i must add some code to my project?**

- i try use taskkill.exe - but "TrayApp.exe" removing from taskmanager but stay on system tray until i move the mouse pointer to tray icon.

Comment: <Property Id="MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL" Value="Disable" /> solved my problem. thanks.

Comment: It solved my problem also but it takes too long when uninstall. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To close the Trayapp at the time of uninstall you need to write a custom action with taskkill.exe.This custom action will kill the Trayapp and then uninstall the application.